# psycopg2: "UnboundLocalError","evalue":"local variable 'connection' referenced before assignment"

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a psycopg2 connection which I am using to connect to postgresql from pyspark. Here is my code -

```
host = 'IP Address'
port = 'Port'
user = 'postgres'
db = 'postgres'
password = 'password'

def move_records(main_table,stg_table):
    try: 
        connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host,
                                             database=db,
                                             user=user,
                                             password=password,
                                             #driver = driver,
                                             port = port)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        move_query = "INSERT INTO " +main_table+ " select * from "+stg_table+" where country ='USA'"
        cursor.execute(move_query)
        connection.commit()
        logger.debug("Record moved successfully")
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
        logger.error("%s Error in transction Reverting all other operations of a transaction ", error)
        global flag
        flag = False
        connection.rollback()
    finally:
        if(connection):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            logger.debug("PostgreSQL connection is closed")

move_records(table_1,table_2)
```

But I keep getting error below error on line if(connection):

```
"UnboundLocalError","evalue":"local variable 'connection' referenced before assignment"
```

Can not figure out what is the issue. Need help.

Comment: psycopg2 fails to connect to the database, that's why there is no local variable `connection`, set `connection = None` before the `try` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in Python but I have worked on similar thing, connecting from Python to Postgres in in AWS Lambda using psycopg2.

I believe the error lies somewhere in scope of variable. You need to declare all variables(host, port, user, db, password) inside function once again as ***global*** or ***nonlocal*** and then try to run function.

For your reference, check out this [link](https://medium.com/@vbsreddy1/unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value-in-python-e34e097547d6#:%7E:text=UnboundLocalError%3A%20local%20variable%20referenced%20before%20assignment%20in%20Python.,-VINTA%20BHARATH%20SAI&text=In%20Python%2C%20variables%20that%20are,unless%20explicitly%20declared%20as%20global.):-